# Hide First Element Then Show Another With Delay - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want one element to hide first, then show another one.

```
$('#removeadminbtn').click(function(){
    //some backend code
    if (error) {
        //
     } else {
         $('#removeadminbtn').hide();
         $('#makeadminbtn').delay(5000).fadeIn();
     }
});
```

This is not working at all. it display `makeadminbtn` first, then hide `removeadminbtn`.

Comment: Please include all relevant code, include your html

Comment: Btw your code works just fine. Try look https://jsfiddle.net/ujwytbb1/ . make sure you have included jquery correctly

Comment: there is no issue with your code. Can you add the HTML and css too?

Comment: basically i am using firebase, it may behaving wrong due to that.

Answer (score 1):

Use [hide callback](http://api.jquery.com/hide/#hide-duration-complete):

```
$('#removeadminbtn').click(function(){
    //some backend code
    if (error) {
        //
     } else {
         $('#removeadminbtn').hide(350, function() { 
            $('#makeadminbtn').fadeIn();
         });

     }
});
```